# JavaFX How can I distinguish between a keyPressed X and a combination of Keys X + Y

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

I want my application (JavaFx 14) to so something when the key "a" is pressed and I also want the application to do something when a key combination with the same key "a" and  "b" is pressed. The goal is to only call one method. the method for pressing a or the method for pressing a +b. I tried doing it with a observable List with keycodes but all methods are called.

```
    private ObservableList<KeyCode> keys = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private void keyboardShortcuts(Button[] buttons){

    // collect pressed key
    scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (e) -> {
        if (!keys.contains(e.getCode())) {
            keys.add(e.getCode());
        }

        e.consume();
    });

    // remove pressed key when it is released   
    scene.setOnKeyReleased((e) -> {
        keys.remove(e.getCode());

        e.consume();
    });

    keys.addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {


            if(keys.size() == 1) {

                if(keys.contains(KeyCode.A)) {
                    foo();
                }
                if(keys.contains(KeyCode.B)) {
                    foo2();
                }                  

            }  
            if(keys.size() == 2) {

                if(keys.contains(KeyCode.A) && keys.contains(KeyCode.B)) {
                    foo3();
                }           

            } 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This works as expected for me.

Comment: Sorry. I was not clear in my question. I only want either the method for pressing a or the method for pressing a + b to be called. I dont dont both methods.                                    #I clearified it in the question

Comment: The user can't press both keys at the same exact time: one of them has to occur first. The method associated with the first key press will be invoked, followed by the method for both keys. This is perfectly normal: if you think about typing, if you want to type an uppercase A using shift+a, you always press shift first, and then press a while holding down shift. If you did it the other way around, you'd get the wrong result.

Comment: Yes. I understand that part. I try to find a way to accomplish my beahviour.

Comment: The only way you could do that would be to introduce a delay: don't respond to individual key presses immediately, but wait a short time to see if another key press occurs "soon" afterwards. Of course, that comes at the expense of responsiveness. Are you sure it's not better for one of the keys (e.g. b) not to have its own functionality?

Comment: Ok thank you. It might be better but I try to achieve some kind of natural mapping with the keys. So I can't change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user "presses two keys", it's impossible for both key presses to happen simultaneously, so one of the key presses will necessarily be detected before the other. Probably the best approach here is to ensure one of the keys (say <kbd>B</kbd>) doesn't have it's own functionality. That way the user will learn to always press <kbd>B</kbd> first, then <kbd>A</kbd> while <kbd>B</kbd> is held down (this is the way we type, using modifier keys such as <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>).

If you really want both keys to have their own functionality, but different functionality when both are pressed "at the same time", then your only option is to implement a delay in handling the press of a single key, waiting to see if the other key is pressed before that delay expires. This, of course, comes at the expense of responsiveness.

Here's an implementation of that, using a short (25ms) `PauseTransition` for the delay. (I also changed to use an `ObservableSet`, which cleans up some of the logic.)

```
private ObservableSet<KeyCode> keys = FXCollections.observableSet();
private PauseTransition keyDelay = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(25));

private void keyboardShortcuts(Scene scene){

    // collect pressed key
    scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (e) -> {
        keys.add(e.getCode());
        e.consume();
    });

    // remove pressed key when it is released   
    scene.setOnKeyReleased((e) -> {
        keys.remove(e.getCode());
        e.consume();
    });

    keys.addListener((Change<? extends KeyCode> c) -> {
        if (keys.size() <= 1) {
            keyDelay.playFromStart();
        } else {
            keyDelay.stop();
            checkKeys();
        }
    });
    keyDelay.setOnFinished(e -> checkKeys());

}

private void checkKeys() {

    if(keys.contains(KeyCode.A) && keys.contains(KeyCode.B)) {
        System.out.println("A and B");
    } else if(keys.contains(KeyCode.A)) {
        System.out.println("A only");
    } else if(keys.contains(KeyCode.B)) {
        System.out.println("B only");
    }
}
```